# diff reports two files differ, although they are the same!

Tags: diff

I have two files which look identical to me (including trailing whitespaces and newlines) but diff still says they differ. Even when I do a `diff -y` side by side comparison the lines look exactly the same. The output from diff is the whole 2 files.

Any idea what's causing it?

Comment: Try to compare unprintable characters. The simplest way to watch them is `sed -n l filename`. If it won't help, add a data example and `diff` output here.

Comment: Ahh yes thank you, the lines in a file are ending with $ and in the other one ending with \r$

Comment: A quick fix is to use dos2unix on both the files (or the one you suspect to be from a Windows machine).

Comment: As a complement to existing answers: the `file` command will hint you about file content, including things like `ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators` vs `ASCII text`.

Comment: I know that I’m late to the party, and *this specific question* has been answered (i.e., MinaHany’s problem has been solved), but — anybody who has a problem like this should do an `ls -l` (or `stat`) on both files and compare the sizes (and include that information in any question). That’s a minimal, obvious first step toward diagnosing the situation.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Odd .. can you try `cmp`? You may want to use the '`-b`' option too.

[cmp man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cmp) - Compare two files byte by byte.

This is one of the nice things about Unix/Linux .. so many tools :)

Comment: Thanks for that! I got: byte 19, line 1 is  15 ^M  12 ^J
what does it mean?

Comment: looks like carriage return and linefeed according to [this table](http://ascii-table.com/control-chars.php)

Comment: tried -b with the diff and it seems to be working for me. man page says `-b` is for `ignore changes in the amount of white space`.

Comment: `cmp` is not always very efficient  : in my case, it only provides a useless `/tmp/w /tmp/z differ: byte 48, line 1 is  12 ^J  12 ^J`, while `cat -t` clearly states that the difference is that lines of the first file end with `^M`.

Answer (score 33):

Try:

```
diff file1 file2 | cat -t
```

The `-t` option will cause `cat` to show any special characters clearly - eg. `^M` for CR, `^I` for tab.

From the man page (OS X):

> ```
>  -t      Display non-printing characters (see the -v option), and display tab characters as `^I'.
>
>  -v      Display non-printing characters so they are visible.
>          Control characters print as `^X' for control-X; the delete character
>          (octal 0177) prints as `^?'.  Non-ASCII characters
>          (with the high bit set) are printed as `M-' (for meta) followed by the
>          character for the low 7 bits.
> ```

Answer (score 18):

Might the differences be caused by DOS vs. UNIX line endings, or something similar?

What if you `hexdump` them? This might show differences more obviously, eg:

```
hexdump -C file1 > file1.hex
hexdump -C file2 > file2.hex
diff file1.hex file2.hex
```

Comment: Well, the two hexes are different. every time there's a 0d 0a in a file the other one just has 0a

Comment: In one, you have DOS line endings (CRLF) and in the other, UNIX line endings (LF). That's why they look different to diff but not when you look at them visually. Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Conversion_utilities

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot. Levon's suggestion of using cmp shows the difference more clearly though :)

Answer (score 6):

My first guess, which turns out to be confirmed, is that the files use different line endings. It could be some other difference in whitespace, such as the presence of trailing whitespace (but you typically wouldn't get that on many lines) or different indentation (tabs vs spaces). Use a command that prints out whitespace and control characters in a visible form, such as

```
diff <(cat -A file1) <(cat -A file2)
diff <(sed -n l file1) <(sed -n l file2)
```

You can confirm that the differences only have to do with line endings by normalizing them first. You may have a `dos2unix` utility; if not, remove the extra CR (^M, \r, \015) character explicitly:

```
diff <(tr -d '\r' <file1) <(tr -d '\r' <file2)
```

or, if `file1` is the one with DOS endings

```
 tr -d '\r' <file1 | diff - file2
```

Answer (score 4):

Other answers are complete enough, but in providing ways of showing somehow invisible differences explicitly. However, there's another option: ignoring these differences, which are somehow unimportant. In some cases, it's not useful to be informed about these differences.

`diff` command has some useful options regarding this:

```
--strip-trailing-cr
    strip trailing carriage return on input

-B, --ignore-blank-lines
    ignore changes where lines are all blank

-Z, --ignore-trailing-space
    ignore white space at line end
```

Personally, I found `--strip-trailing-cr` useful, especially when using `-r` (i.e. `--recursive`) option on large projects, or when Git's [`core.autocrlf`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#_code_core_autocrlf_code) is not `false` (i.e. is either `true` or `input`).

For more information on these options and more, see [its man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/diff) (or via `man diff`).

**Note:** Using these options affects the performance of getting results, especially in the case of huge files/directories. In one of my own cases, it increased the manipulation time from `0.321s` to `0.422s`.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone on Windows you can do this with fc. It can use binary compare.

```
fc /B file1 file2
```

Comment: Hi Johan, and welcome to the UNIX & Linux Stack Exchange! Our target systems here are UNIX/Linux systems; you might find Windows-centric answers more on-topic at SuperUser or Server Fault. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In **side-by-side** view add `--suppress-common-lines` to the options.

All other answers and comments here, are good to know, but **not sufficient** at all. The original question is **explicitly about side-by-side** comparison. Even files produced with `cp` will be completely listed in side-by-side mode - all problems with line feed, spaces or special characters aside. You will always need `--suppress-common-lines` to get the desired result.

This may be not obvious for non english natives, as *common* may be interpreted as 'normal' and not 'mutual'. Perhaps it would be easier if it was saying 'suppress-equal-lines' or similar. And I was really surprised that there was no short, one letter option for such a 'common' :) task.